# @EnableTransactionManagement annotation with 2 transaction managers

Tags: java, spring, spring-3, spring-annotations

I am using `@Configuration` annotation for configuration of spring instead of xml file. I am configuring 2 datasources with different session factory and different transaction managers. I am stuck with a problem here for `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation. I read in its documentation that,

> `@EnableTransactionManagement` is more flexible; it will fall back to a
>   by-type lookup for any `PlatformTransactionManager` bean in the
>   container. Thus the name can be "txManager", "transactionManager", or
>   "tm": it simply does not matter.

This means whatever name I give to method, it will always search for the method which returns `PlatformTransactionManager` object while I have 2 transactionmanagers. Now the problem is, when I test this class, it gives me error:

> `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`: No unique bean of type [`org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager`] is defined: expected single bean but found 2

I even tried to have 2 different Configuration classes but in vain. In xml configuration, this was not the case. I registered my both transaction managers with two `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="" />` tag and it worked fine. But not able to do same here with annotations.

What should I do if I want to configure 2 datasources with 2 different transaction managers in Spring annotated configuration class?

Comment: This may be a bug, since Spring 3.1 is still in beta/rc stage.

Answer (score 38):

In your configuration class, use `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation.

Define a transaction manager in this class as:

```
    @Bean(name="txName")
    public HibernateTransactionManager txName() throws IOException{
        HibernateTransactionManager txName= new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txName.setSessionFactory(...);
        txName.setDataSource(...);
        return txName;
   }
```

There on, in your class/method that executes transactional job(s), annotate as follows:

```
@Transactional("txName")
```

or

```
@Transactional(value = "txName")
```

This is how you would tie a name qualified transaction manager to wherever you need it. You can now have as many transaction managers as you want and use it accordingly wherever you need.

Comment: This helped a lot. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Just in case anyone runs into this problem, I found a solution:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@DependsOn("myTxManager")
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class AppConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

@Autowired
private PlatformTransactionManager myTxManager;

...

@Override
public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
    return this.myTxManager;
}
```

In this way, you can use a specific txManager defined in an xml configuration.

In case you want to define the *txManager* used on service-level, you shall **remove** the `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation from the `@Configuration` class and specify the *txManager* in the `@Transactional` annotations, e.g.

```
@Service
@Transactional(value="myTxManager", readOnly = true)
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService { ... }
```

Comment: You can configure as many `txManager`s as you want in XML, and you can use any of the configured `txManager`s on applications or service level by using the `@DependsOn()` or `@Transactional()` annotation described above

Answer (score 5):

From the [java doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html)

> For those that wish to establish a more direct relationship between
>       `@EnableTransactionManagement` and the exact transaction manager bean to be used, the 
>       `TransactionManagementConfigurer` callback interface may be implemented - notice the 
>       implements clause and the `@Override`-annotated method below:

Your `@Configuration` class needs to implement `TransactionManagementConfigurer` interface - implement the `annotationDrivenTransactionManager` which will return the reference to the `transactionManager` that should be used.

Comment: I had read this also. But the problem here is, that implemented method calls the transactionmanager method and returns the same transaction manager object, while I want to have 2 transaction managers in my configuration class. And as @EnableTransactionManagement does not see the method name, just falls to see which is the PlatformTransactionManagement object, it will not allow 2 transaction managers in configuration.

Comment: just return the reference to the one that you want used by @EnableTransactionManagement from annotationDrivenTransactionManager method

Comment: That is where the problem is. It's not fixed which transaction manager will be used as it depends on the model object. I have 2 models from 2 different databases but entries are done at same time in both of them. Now, if anyhow, data could not be inserted in 1 table, the other entry should be discarded as well and thus transaction rollback can happen anywhere.

Comment: You cannot use two transaction managers for the same request / transaction.  The facility is provided to be used in two different requests. If you want a transaction spanning multiple requests you should use a single JTATransactionManager.  What your asking now is not supported in the xml namespace version as well (tx:annotation-driven)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are using two TransactionManagers . You could consider using the same TransactionManager for multiple datasource via the AbstractRoutingDataSource . Please refer

http://blog.springsource.org/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

for a sample on its usage.

Comment: Separate TransactionManager DB and JMS for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **chained TransactionalManager**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Configuration
public class ChainedDBConfig {

    @Bean("chainedTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("database1TransactionManager") final PlatformTransactionManager db1PlatformTransactionManager,
            @Qualifier("database2TransactionManager") final PlatformTransactionManager db2PlatformTransactionManager) {

        return new ChainedTransactionManager(db1PlatformTransactionManager, db2PlatformTransactionManager);
    }

}
```

And place the following annotation on your service class:

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "chainedTransactionManager")
public class AggregateMessagesJobIntegrationTest {
   ...
}
```

You can also use it inside the integration tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Transactional(transactionManager = "chainedRawAndAggregatedTransactionManager")
@Rollback
public class ExampleIntegrationTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {
    ....
}
```

and it will do a rollback for both DB transaction managers.

Comment: works properly, thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I have to use JPA and Reactive Mongo in one project. What works at last was:

- create a `@Configuraition` class to explicitly create a JPA transaction manager, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861439/no-bean-named-transactionmanager-available):

```java
    private Environment env;
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean dbEntityManager() {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            em.setDataSource(dbDatasource());
            em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"projectone.mysql"});
            em.setPersistenceUnitName("dbEntityManager");
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

            HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

            properties.put("hibernate.dialect",env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            properties.put("hibernate.show-sql",env.getProperty("jdbc.show-sql"));


            em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
            return em;
        }
        @Primary
        @Bean
        public DataSource dbDatasource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource
                    = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(
                    env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driverClassName"));
            dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
            dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
            return dataSource;
        }
        @Primary
        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                    = new JpaTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                    dbEntityManager().getObject());
            return transactionManager;
        }

}
```

**Notice that the bean name `jpaTransactionManager`, which would be the txManager name used in JPA `@Transactional`.**

- create `MongoConfiguration` to explicitly create a Mongo transaction manager(a lot of beans to define)
- in `@Transactional`, call them with name. The default one `transactionManger` will not work. You have to distinguish, like `jpaTransactionManager` and `reactiveMongoTransactionManger`.

```
@Transactional(value="jpaTransactionManager")
public void xxx() {
    ...
}
```

Note that JPA transaction methods cannot Reactor types as return value(Mono/Flux). Spring will force methods returning Mono/Flux to use ReactiveTransactionManager, it will cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers imply that using two transaction managers is in some way wrong; however, Spring's XML configuration allows for using multiple transaction managers as stated in the online documentation (below).  Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a way to make the `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation work in a similar manner.  As a result, I simply use an `@ImportResource` annotation to load an XML file that includes the `<tx:annotation-driven/>` line.  This allows you to get a Java configuration for most things but still make use of `@Transactional` with an optional Transaction Manager qualifier.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

> Most Spring applications only need a single transaction manager, but there may be situations where you want multiple independent transaction managers in a single application. The value attribute of the `@Transactional` annotation can be used to optionally specify the identity of the `PlatformTransactionManager` to be used. This can either be the bean name or the qualifier value of the transaction manager bean. For example, using the qualifier notation, the following Java code