# Multiple transaction managers annotation configuration

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations, config

I have two transaction managers configured in annotation-based configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DBConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

//...

@Override
public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
    return defTransactionManager();
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("defSessionFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean defSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sfb.setDataSource(defDataSource());

    Properties props = new Properties();
    //...

    sfb.setHibernateProperties(props);
    sfb.setPackagesToScan("my.package");

    return sfb;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("defTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager defTransactionManager() {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(defSessionFactory().getObject());
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("secondSessionFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean secondSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sfb.setDataSource(secondDataSource());

    Properties props = new Properties();
    //...

    sfb.setHibernateProperties(props);
    sfb.setPackagesToScan("my.package.subpackage");

    return sfb;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("secondTM")
public PlatformTransactionManager secondTransactionManager() {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(secondSessionFactory().getObject());
}
}
```

My intention is use annotation transactions with two transaction managers.
Methonds annotated like this

```
@Transactional
public void method() {}
```

should be handled by defTransactionManager

And methods annotated like this

```
@Transactional("secondTM")
public void anotherMethod() {}
```

by secondTransactionManager

defTransactionManager works fine but when it comes to anotherMethod() I get:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

When I use programmatic transaction management for anotherMethod (autowire secondSessionFactory, use TransactionTemplate) everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

In case of [@EnableTranscationManagement](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) Spring will use by-type lookup, you can provide  your own lookup method to a single transaction manager, but [it will not work for two tx managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050183/enabletransactionmanagement-annotation-with-2-transaction-managers)

If you want to check how Spring determines the transaction to execute, you can try to debug the [TransactionAspectSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport.html) class. The key methods are `setTransactionManagerBeanName` and `determineTransactionManager`.

Comment: I expect this because my configuration class implements TransactionManagementConfigurer and the overriden method annotationDrivenTransactionManager returns defTransactionManager()

Comment: @AlexanderCamperov is it a web application?

Comment: Have you checked if `@Transactional()` works on the exactly the same beans you where you expect `@Transactional("secondTM")` to work?

Comment: I cannot do this, they meant to work with different datasources and different entities. Actually they worked fine before I started migrating my project from xml configuration to annotation configuration.

Comment: Also there's a little chance that the beans, where @@Transactional does not work, are actually residing in another context where AOP interceptors are not declared. For example if your transaction configuration works in root app context, but the @@Transactional annotation is declared on the servlet context beans - e.g. if they were accidentally picked by autoscanning and created in servlet context.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone runs into this problem, I found a solution:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@DependsOn("myTxManager")
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class AppConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

@Autowired
private PlatformTransactionManager myTxManager;

...

@Override
public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
    return this.myTxManager;
}
```

In this way, you can use a specific txManager defined in an xml configuration.

In case you want to define the *txManager* used on service-level, you shall **remove** the `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation from the `@Configuration` class and specify the *txManager* in the `@Transactional` annotations, e.g.

```
@Service
@Transactional(value="myTxManager", readOnly = true)
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService { ... }
```

Comment: I have also similar kind of problem. I am able to use two transaction manager but my delete query is not working.