# expected single matching bean but found 2: transactionManager1,transactionManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to use to different data sources. But I am getting above exception.
Here is my **spring-config.xml**

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<tx:annotation-driven />


<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager1"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory1" />
</bean>
```

Here is my **exception**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: transactionManager1,transactionManager
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:365)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:370)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:271)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getVehiclePositions(Unknown Source)
at com.scorpionauto.service.impl.GetDataService.getVehiclePositionsDetails(GetDataService.java:71)
at com.scorpionauto.controller.GetDataController.getVehiclePosition(GetDataController.java:23)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

From comments

```
@Transactional()
public ArrayList<Integer> getDevicePendingAlerts(int userId, String deviceId) {
    String country = "IND";
    Criteria criteria;
    if (country.equalsIgnoreCase("UK")) {
        criteria = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(DeviceAlerts.class);
    } else {
        criteria = getSessionFactory1().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(DeviceAlerts.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use the `@Qualifier` annotation in your code to tell spring which transaction manager do you would like to use. For more help we need to see your code of `GetDataService`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20806857/3898076

Comment: @Transactional()
 public ArrayList<Integer> getDevicePendingAlerts(int userId,String deviceId)
 {
  String country="IND";
  Criteria criteria;
  if(country.equalsIgnoreCase("UK"))
  {
   criteria = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(DeviceAlerts.class);
  }
  else
  {
   criteria = getSessionFactory1().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(DeviceAlerts.class);
  }
  

 }

}

Comment: @AjaykumarKadam, you can edit your question and add your code inside it.

Answer (score 34):

Refer : [@EnableTransactionManagement annotation with 2 transaction managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050183/enabletransactionmanagement-annotation-with-2-transaction-managers)

`@Transactional(value={METHOD,TYPE})` documentation for [value](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#value--) states that

> A qualifier value for the specified transaction.
>
> May be used to **determine the target transaction manager**, matching the
>   qualifier value (or the bean name) of a specific
>   *PlatformTransactionManager* bean definition.

You need to add **qualifier** to point out which transaction manager to use.
Just change `@Transactional()` to `@Transactional("transactionManager")` or `@Transactional("transactionManager1")` whichever transaction Manager you want to use.

Comment: @AjaykumarKadam, did your problem get solve? If yes then you can accept this answer, so that others will get benefited in future.

Comment: @NamanGala Sorry for the late reply.  It worked for me and forget to reply.

Comment: @AjaykumarKadam can you accept the answer, since you mentioned it's working for you.

Comment: how to use multiple transactionManger in single method ?