# No bean named 'transactionManager' available in SpringBoot JPA Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

According to baeldung [here](https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring)

> If we're using a Spring Boot project, and have a spring-data-* or spring-tx >dependencies on the classpath, then transaction management will be enabled by >default."

However, i have this error:

> org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@788f2bfc]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' available: No matching TransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!

with these Dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.indra.icens</groupId>
        <artifactId>ic-license</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>mq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>mqjms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
        <artifactId>connector</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.indra.icens.srom</groupId>
        <artifactId>ic_int_srom_common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://xxx/yyy
spring.datasource.username=asdasd
spring.datasource.password=werwer
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
```

ServiceConfig.java

```
@EnableJms
@Configuration
@ImportResource({
"classpath:/META-INF/spring/integration/main-config.xml"
})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.nbi.conn.repository")
@EntityScan("com.nbi.conn.entities")
public class ServiceConfig {
}
```

what is wrong ?, what am i missing in my SpringBoot Config?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to add a bean "transactionManager" in your config like this

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

    return transactionManager;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, it worked! However, I have the doubt of the correct configuration since in another similar project I did not need to configure this bean.

Thank you

Comment: Adding this solved my problem. But the real cause was that I had one transitive dependency including spring-cloud-gcp-data-datastore in my classpath which was causing many conflicts